# Android application lag in different phone but same processor

Tags: android

I built an android application and am I now in the testing phase. I tested my application on the following 2 devices:

- Sony Xperia Z3
- One Plus One

Both devices have the same processor and ram, but the performance on Sony Z3 is laggy whereas on OnePlus One it is smooth. I looked up about this on google but I couldn't find an answer.

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: There may be many reasons for this like the amount of apps installed, storage space left, apps running in background and **most importantly** the OS i.e. Sony uses modified ROM called Xperia UI and OnePlus One uses CyanogenMod/OxygenOS which is faster basically.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder if really because of the modified ROM, is that any ways I can make it no lag in the devices?

Comment: Well that is a very broad topic but the following Google documentation is a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Android applications lag on the devices may have various background. If the UX of your app suffers from lagging it's worth learning [tools that Android Studio comes with](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/index.html). This is my suspicion based on your description but I suggest focusing in particular on [Method Profiler](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) as it will immediately indicate the causes of lags. Mostly probably there are some heavy calculations executed or massive objects creation performed on the UI thread.

Alternatively, the following libraries will help you with detecting sensitive places that the application's performance may suffer from:

https://github.com/brianPlummer/TinyDancer

https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Pretty good working example below:

https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters